# Display voting results directly in reading pane of outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

An email dispatcher should have control about emails that are redirected by him. Therefore all emails redirected have custom voting buttons "Accept" and  "Decline". User now has to "vote" if email is processed by him, dispatcher should have a easy way to check which emails are accepted/declined.

So I need a solution like:
- attach automatically voting buttons to new email (MailItem.VotingOptions Property)
- User should have a easy way to "reach" voting buttons (e.g show voting buttons directly in reading pane without hover over the information row)
- Dispatcher should see voting results of redirected email directly in reading pane (now you have to open the email an click Status button).

I use Outlook 2016/Exchange 2016 ...

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It seems you forgot to show your code.

Comment: Up to now I have no code. I dont know whats the best way to implement that: VBA Solution or C# add in. I have little experience with Outlook development, I know VBA of MS Access as well as C# and web development (MVC).

Comment: If you going to run it on one machine only, create a VBA script in Outlook. Otherwise create a c# add-in for Outlook.